# What is the least expensive way to test if a View has been recycled?

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

I have a caching bean that I use to look up/store information about objects in an app. I want to do as few fetching of Views as possible as I would imagine each Database.getView comes at some cost.

What is the least expensive way to trigger "View has been recycled"?

Comment: I had this question too, but have stepped away from caching Domino objects since reading http://www.intec.co.uk/object-has-been-removed-or-recycled-when-logic-goes-wrong/ by Paul Withers. I now only cache UNID's or values from document fields. Like Nathan says in the comments, we could use an "isRecycled()" method in Domino objects.

Comment: I never cache documents. The reason I wanted to cache the view was that document lookups are ad-hoc/per item. Document values are read into beans when the bean data isn't current any more. Sometimes there might be 100+ lookups (=100+ getView). I still get good perfomance when the view isn't cached, but if I could get even better performance, that would be nice :)

Comment: You can expect every Notes object is recycled after request phase.

Comment: You could initialize the view in the caller and pass it as a parameter on each method call. For instance, define the view in the XPage and pass it each time you do a lookup as a parameter to the Java method or bean. I think you'll be save during a single request

Comment: Everything in regards to this question is happening in beans, but your proposal still holds. This will take care of doing getView for every lookup. It looks like there is little experimentation into checking if Views have been recycled, so I'll probably just avoid the problem and write a few extra lines of code where it's needed. A public isRecycled-method would be nice :)

Comment: I deleted my answer because this version of the *isRecycled* method works better. It additionally checks the C object handle.

Comment: That's what I also discovered in my magic crystal ball ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After inspiration from Sven Hasselbach, I created this method:

```
/*
Classes that need to be imported:
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import lotus.domino.Base;
import lotus.domino.local.NotesBase;
*/

public static boolean isRecycled( Base object ) {
    boolean isRecycled = true;
    if( ! ( object instanceof NotesBase ) ) { 
        // No reason to test non-NotesBase objects -> isRecycled = true
        return isRecycled;
    }

    try {
        NotesBase notesObject = (NotesBase) object;
        Method isDead = notesObject.getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredMethod( "isDead" );
        isDead.setAccessible( true );       

        isRecycled = (Boolean) isDead.invoke( notesObject );
    } catch ( Throwable exception ) {
        // Exception handling
    }

    return isRecycled;
}
```

**Update:** It seems using this method requires changes to java.policy. Specifically this line: *notesObject.getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredMethod( "isDead" )*

Comment: This throws a SecurityException on my 853 server ("not allowed to access members in class class lotus.domino.local.NotesDatabase") on the line to retrieve the isDead declared method. I have a default java.policy. Did you change that file?

Comment: @MarkLeusink: Please try a grant for *permission java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission* *"suppressAccessChecks";*

Comment: Thanks for the tip. That will probably work, but I don't want to change the Java policy only to be able to check if a object is recycled or not.

Answer (score 3):

How about a tester class designed to test the various Domino objects?

You could perform an operation which would throw an exception if the object was recycled -instead of just testing for null. Would something like the following code work, or am I being overly simplistic?

```
package com.azlighthouse.sandbox;

import lotus.domino.Database;
import lotus.domino.Document;
import lotus.domino.NotesException;

public class NPHchecker {

    public static boolean isRecycled(Document source, boolean printStackTrace) {
        try {
            return (source.getUniversalID().length() > 0);
        } catch (NotesException e) {
            if (printStackTrace)
                e.printStackTrace();
            return true;
        }
    } // isRecycled(Document, boolean)

    public static boolean isRecycled(Database source, boolean printStackTrace) {
        try {
            return (source.getReplicaID().length() > 0);
        } catch (NotesException e) {
            if (printStackTrace)
                e.printStackTrace();
            return true;
        }
    } // isRecycled(Database, boolean)


}  // NPHchecker
```

Comment: That was my intention. The only trouble is that I don't know which method calls are cached. E.g. NotesView.getUniversalID() or NotesView.getName() might return a cached value even if the view has been recycled.

Comment: I like this way much more because it's very difficult to push changes to java.policy files of big companies. I haven't run into cache issues yet.